# Ruby array of paths, sort and delete if included in another item

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Hello i have a array of system pathes and want to sort out the paths witch are include in another path. i have for example:

```
 ["images/2014",
 "images/2014/4chan",
 "images/2014/4chan/brom",
 "images/4chan",
 "images/somthing",
 "images/somthing/brom",
 "images/somthing/frueher",
 "images/somthing/royo"]
```

and i want to have:

```
["images/2014/4chan/brom",
 "images/4chan",
 "images/somthing/brom",
 "images/somthing/frueher",
 "images/somthing/royo"]
```

i was thinking of something like `include?` but i don't get it working

```
all_folders.combination(2).any? do |a, b|
  if a.include? b
    all_folders.delete b
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [
  "images/2014",
  "images/2014/4chan",
  "images/2014/4chan/brom",
  "images/4chan",
  "images/somthing",
  "images/somthing/brom",
  "images/somthing/frueher",
  "images/somthing/royo"
]
```

```
(arr.sort << "").each_cons(2).
                 reject { |x,y| y.start_with?(x) }.
                 map(&:first)
  #=> ["images/2014/4chan/brom",
  #    "images/4chan",
  #    "images/somthing/brom",
  #    "images/somthing/frueher",
  #    "images/somthing/royo"]
```

The computational complexity is that of `sort`, O(nlog(n)), n being the size of `arr`.

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.sort
  #=> ["images/2014", "images/2014/4chan", "images/2014/4chan/brom",
  #    "images/4chan", "images/somthing", "images/somthing/brom", 
  #    "images/somthing/frueher", "images/somthing/royo"] 
b = a << ""
  #=> ["images/2014",..., "images/somthing/royo", ""] 
enum = b.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["images/2014", "images/2014/4chan",...
  #                  "images/somthing/royo", ""]:each_cons(2)>
```

We can see the objects that will be generated by `enum` by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["images/2014", "images/2014/4chan"],
  #    ["images/2014/4chan", "images/2014/4chan/brom"],
  #    ["images/2014/4chan/brom", "images/4chan"], 
  #    ["images/4chan", "images/somthing"], 
  #    ["images/somthing", "images/somthing/brom"], 
  #    ["images/somthing/brom", "images/somthing/frueher"], 
  #    ["images/somthing/frueher", "images/somthing/royo"],
  #    ["images/somthing/royo", ""]]
```

Continuing,

```
b = enum.reject { |x,y| y.start_with?(x) }
  #=> [["images/2014/4chan/brom", "images/4chan"], 
  #    ["images/4chan", "images/somthing"], 
  #    ["images/somthing/brom", "images/somthing/frueher"], 
  #    ["images/somthing/frueher", "images/somthing/royo"],
  #    ["images/somthing/royo", ""]] 
b.map(&:first)
  #=> ["images/2014/4chan/brom", "images/4chan",
  #    "images/somthing/brom", "images/somthing/frueher",
  #    "images/somthing/royo"]
```

If array order is to be maintained:

```
arr.shuffle!
  #=> ["images/somthing/royo", "images/2014", "images/4chan",
  #    "images/somthing", "images/2014/4chan/brom",
  #    "images/2014/4chan", "images/somthing/frueher",
  #    "images/somthing/brom"] 

order = arr.each_with_index.to_h
  #=> {"images/somthing/royo"=>0, "images/2014"=>1,
  #    "images/4chan"=>2, "images/somthing"=>3,
  #    "images/2014/4chan/brom"=>4, "images/2014/4chan"=>5,
  #    "images/somthing/frueher"=>6, "images/somthing/brom"=>7}

(arr.sort << "").each_cons(2).
                 reject { |x,y| y.start_with?(x) }.
                 map(&:first).
                 sort_by { |s| order[s] } 
  #=> ["images/somthing/royo", "images/4chan",
  #    "images/2014/4chan/brom", "images/somthing/frueher",
  #    "images/somthing/brom"]
```

Comment: i like the simplicity of this approach, but don't quite understand all parts.
Whats `<< ""` for and the `map(&:first)`?

Comment: Let's first deal with `map(&:first)`. Look at my array `b` after "Continuing," above. It contains 5 elements, each element an array of size 2. `b.map(&:first)` produces the same array as `b.map { |x| x.first }` (`x` being a 2-element array), which is the same as `b.map { |y,z| y }`.

Comment: `<< ""` is merely a trick to allow me to write a single expression. Suppose `<< ""` were not present. Then the last element in `enum.to_a` above (`["images/somthing/royo"]`) would not be generated by the enumerator. Therefore, the array returned would not include `"images/somthing/royo"`, which is the last element of `arr.sort`. As the last element of `arr.sort` should *always* be included, I could have (and for clarity, perhaps should have) saved `arr.sort` to a variable (`a = arr.sort`), then appended the array to be returned with `a.last`...

Comment: ... By writing `<< ""`, the array `["images/somthing/royo", ""]` is not `reject`ed, because `"".start_with?("images/somthing/royo")` is never true.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
in_ar = ["images/2014",
 "images/2014/4chan",
 "images/2014/4chan/brom",
 "images/4chan",
 "images/somthing",
 "images/somthing/brom",
 "images/somthing/frueher",
 "images/somthing/royo"]
 
def included_in_paths?(target, paths)
  paths.any? do |path|
    next if path == target
    path.include? target
  end
end


result = in_ar.reject do |path|
  included_in_paths?(path, in_ar)
end

## use Array#reject! if you want to change the original array

p(result == ["images/2014/4chan/brom",
 "images/4chan",
 "images/somthing/brom",
 "images/somthing/frueher",
 "images/somthing/royo"]
) # -> true
```

Comment: You may wish to write `path.start_with? target` rather than `path.include? target`. It's both faster and avoids an error when, for example `path` is `"a/b"` and `target` is `"b"`.

Comment: i also tried with `inlcude?` but had the exact same problem when the second argument is within the first and not only at the beginning. 

i tried this, which mostly worked, somehow.

```
def flatten_paths_array(paths)
  paths.combination(2) do |a,b|
    if b.include? a
      paths.delete_if {|x| x == a}
    end
  end

  return paths
end
```

Comment: @rwaffen The question has been answered according to the use case you provided. Maybe you could refine your question with a more detailed use case, particularly what you mean by 'paths witch are included in another path' giving the desired output provided the input.